# Преобразование типа данных nvarchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Пытаюсь создать в **Laravel** пользователя в таблице **users**, для создания даты регистрации использую **Carbon**:

```
'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
```

и при попытке регистрации получаю ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Преобразование типа данных nvarchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.
insert into
  [ users ] (
    [ name ],
    [ email ],
    [ password ],
    [ updated_at ],
    [ created_at ]
  )
values
  (
    name,
    ?,
    password,
    2022 -08 -30 11: 16: 14.084,
    2022 -08 -30 11: 16: 14.084
  )
```

Тип данных таблицы **users** столбца **created_at** и **updated_at** - **datetime**.
Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно прописать в миграции:

```
$table->dateTimeTz('created_at')->nullable();
$table->dateTimeTz('updated_at')->nullable();
```

Он добавляет 7 цифр после точки.